# Button creates at tableFooterView not response to events

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I create a tableView in a class inherit from UIView.It works well when I add a button at tableFooterView on this tableView.

```
CustomView.h
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
@interface CustomView : UIView<UITableViewDelegate,UITableViewDataSource>
@end

CustomView.m
- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForFooterInSection:(NSInteger)section{
    UIView * customView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.bounds.size.width, 80)];
    UIButton * tempButton = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 40)];
    tempButton.center = customView.center;
    tempButton.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
    [tempButton addTarget:self action:@selector(doButtonAction) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [customView addSubview:tempButton];

    return customView;
}

- (void)doButtonAction{
    NSLog(@"123");
}
```

NSLog:123

However,I public this button and make a target-action in my controller.It response nothing.

```
CustomView.h
@property (strong, nonatomic) UIButton * tempButton;

CustomView.m
- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForFooterInSection:(NSInteger)section{
    UIView * customView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.bounds.size.width, 80)];
    self.tempButton = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 40)];
    self.tempButton.center = customView.center;
    [customView addSubview:self.tempButton];
    return customView;
}

ViewController.h

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    CustomView *cv = [[CustomView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.bounds ];
    [cv.tempButton addTarget:self action:@selector(doButtonAction) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [self.view addSubview:cv];
}
- (void)doButtonAction{
    NSLog(@"123");
}
```

what did I miss?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the `viewdidload` you are not set any thing on the button,
You just assign in the `@interface`.

but you must be alloc and set the frame and `backgroundcolor` and all `properties` on the button in the `viewdidload` .

After that it will work.

May be it will help you or feel free.

Comment: That's my fault.I omitted a piece of code.Actually,this button has been alloced on tableFooterView.Curiously enough,this button is nil indeed in the ```viewDidLoad```.